# CollapsingToolbarLayout gets focus all the time (support library 26.0.1)

Tags: android, focus, android-support-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I wanted `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to have inertia that does not work properly in 25.x support library, so I updated to 26.0.1 (it was fixed after years of complaining). But I noticed that now it has another issue: I have `NestedScrollView` with `Button` and some `TextViews` (below `AppBarLayout` that has `CollapsingToolbarLayout`), and I have to press button twise to make it work, because of focus, I suppose. Then I scroll `NestedScrollView` a bit and press some `TextView`s, and after that button works again only after second click.

when I click outside the button `onWindowFocusChanged(true)` in `CollapsingToolbarLayout` triggers.

I tried calling `setFocusable` and `setFocusableInTouchMode`, but without any luck. If you have any ideas how to make button work with first click, please, help.

p.s. 25.3.1 support library does not have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but here's the solution:

https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/8391b5adb9ee42180893300850ed02f2

Just add the class `FixAppBarLayoutBehavior.java` and then add the lines in `Usage.java` to your Activity.

Personally, I find it a bit weird that this fix hasn't been incorporated into the support library yet.